# How do i reconnect to my remote repository from my local

Tags: git, terminal, bitbucket

I cloned a repo from my team's repository which is in bitbucket. I created a new feature branch for myself and checked in some code to my remote feature branch. Suddenly I cannot connect to the remote repository anymore. When i run `'git push origin <my-feature-branch>`, I keep getting *'fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:...'* error which essentially is telling me that the URL does not work. I have updated changes in my local branch that i want to push to my remote branch. how do i do this without having to delete my local setup and create everything over again? I tried running `git init` but no luck. I am on mac, tried this from terminal as well as VS Code. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43835309/1256452)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I keep getting `fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:...`

Redirections are a feature of http/https: a server, getting some request for some URL, sends back a 301, 302, 303, etc., code (see, e.g., [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/q/391181/549786) or [much more detailed Dr Link Check blog entry](https://www.drlinkcheck.com/blog/http-redirects-301-302-303-307-308) to tell you, or whoever sent the URL anyway, that they should be looking elsewhere.

When Git gets such a redirect, it can optionally follow the redirect, or complain (see [What does the warning "redirecting to" actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53012504/1256452) and [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for `http.followRedirects`).  If the redirect itself is *faulty*, it won't be able to follow the redirect.

(The usual problem is that you're using the wrong URL in the first place.  Check the URL carefully.)